# System.Data.SQLite queries execution fails in published VSTO app with FTS5 enabled

Tags: c#, sqlite, vsto, publish, fts5

In my VSTO app I use sqlite `fts5` module. On the development machine the app works OK, but when I publish it and try to execute SELECT query - NOTHING HAPPENS (even no exception is thrown!)!

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        using (SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Categories order by Name", connection))
        {
            adapter.Fill(Globals.ThisAddIn.Categories_Table); //here is the line where the code execution goes to infinity                       
        }
    }
}
catch (SQLiteException ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{ex.Message}\nError code: {ex.ResultCode}\nHResult: {ex.HResult}\nSource: {ex.Source}\nStack trace:\n{ex.StackTrace}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{ex.Message}\nHResult: {ex.HResult}\nSource: {ex.Source}\nStack trace:\n{ex.StackTrace}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Whether Nuget `System.Data.SQLite.Core.FTS5` package is installed or not, it's not working on the client's machine.

I use "Any CPU" configuration and `System.Data.SQLite` nuget package. The development and client machines both use Office 64-Bit.

Is there any solution to make `FTS5` module work on the client's machine?

Comment: Any errors in the event log? Does your addin load?

Comment: Yes, addin loads correctly. No errors in loading.
It executes correctly until ```adapter.fill(...);```

Comment: Did you check the Event Log -> Application Log?

Comment: How can I do it for published app?

Comment: For Win8+ it is: Start button and select Control Panel > System & Security and double-click Administrative tools / Double-click Event Viewer / Select Application Logs

Comment: what happens on `adapter.fill(...);`?

Comment: also do this, if you haven't already: https://www.oneplacesolutions.com/support/0053.html

Comment: Seems like this line ```adapter.fill``` is being executed infinitely

Comment: No logs has been recorded: Neither in Microsoft Office alerts nor in my VSTO app folder (or I just couldn't find them)

Comment: I guess there is nothing to be logged